# Java ternary operator returning type

Tags: java, ternary-operator

```
public class HelloWorld{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    Long myLong = 4L;
    Long everLong = (myLong == null ? 0L : 1);
    System.out.println(everLong);
  }
}
```

If I change "0L" to "0" => I get an "incompatible types" error.

Why is this code compiling and not throwing error while the parameter "1" is not a Long ?

Edit : The answers given as duplicates are stating that an int assigned to a Long don't compile so it doesn't answer my question because in my case it is compiling.

Comment: The problem is not with Java ternary operator is with the literals in java

Comment: With both operands being of type `int`, the entire expression is of type `int`.

Comment: I disagree with this being marked as a duplicate. The referenced answers only address half of the question - the boxing conversion to Long.They fail to explain how the conditional expression is typed.